# I keep getting a " TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType' "

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning python and as practice I wrote some code to find the derivative of a user defined function. The code is as follows.

```
def fx(value, function):
    x = value
    return eval(function)


input_function = raw_input('Input your function using correct python syntax: ')

def derivative_formula(x, h):
    (fx(x - h, input_function) - fx(x + h, input_function)) / 2 * h

def derivative_of_x(x):
    error = 0.0001
    h = 0.1
    V = derivative_formula(x, h)
    h = h / 2
    derivative_estimate = derivative_formula(x, h)
    while abs(derivative_estimate - V) < error:
        V = derivative_formula(x, h)
        h = h / 2
        derivative_estimate = derivative_formula(x, h)
    return derivative_estimate

x1 = float(raw_input('Where do you want to calculate the derivative?'))

return derivative_of_x(x1)
```

The full error code is as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "Derivative.py", line 25, in <module>
        print derivative_of_x(x1)
    File "Derivative.py", line 17, in derivative_of_x
        while abs(derivative_estimate - V) - error:
TypeError: Unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to return anything from your `derivative_formula` function. Try:

```
def derivative_formula(x, h):
    return (fx(x - h, input_function) - fx(x + h, input_function)) / 2 * h
```

Also, if you are trying to divide by 2h, you'll need an additional parenthesis.

```
def derivative_formula(x, h):
    return (fx(x - h, input_function) - fx(x + h, input_function)) / (2 * h)
```

And I think you want to reverse the two function calls there.

```
def derivative_formula(x, h):
    return (fx(x + h, input_function) - fx(x - h, input_function)) / (2 * h)
```

Comment: Thank you, the code now at least returns a value, but it's the wrong value. When I tried to calculate the derivative of x ** 2 at 4 I get -0.02. Is this an issue with the object types that I'm using (float vs dec?) or something to do with my algorithm?

Comment: What value do you expect to get instead of -0.02?

Comment: Yeah, eight is what I'm looking to get

Answer (score 0):

Your `derivative_formula` has no `return` statement which in python defaults to `return None`. Hence when you call `abs(derivative_estimate - V)` you are effectively subtracting a `NoneType` object (`V`) from another `NoneType` object.

What you need is the return statement in `derivative_formula`:

```
def derivative_formula(x, h):
    res = (fx(x - h, input_function) - fx(x + h, input_function)) / 2 * h
    return res
```